# Is it possible to reopen this question?

Tags: discussion

I was unable to explain my point it seems within the question.

[Which mathematical operations leave the ontology invariant?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/104370/which-mathematical-operations-leave-the-ontology-invariant)

Is it possible to reopen this question? (To meet site standards so I don't duplicate a question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was among the five that voted to close this question. Although your [post-closure edit](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/posts/104370/timeline#history_8a7f496a-46af-4ec1-be78-61649fbcffef) addresses [Daniel Asimov's comment](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/104370/which-mathematical-operations-leave-the-ontology-invariant#comment314304_104370) (in my opinion anyway), it does not address the confusion I had (and [JD also expressed in their comment](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/104370/which-mathematical-operations-leave-the-ontology-invariant#comment314395_104370)) regarding the question itself (in both the title and at the end of the question's body):

> What all mathematical operations leave the ontology invariant for a physicist?

Perhaps JD is no longer confused by this terminology anymore (you'll have to ask them), but if the confusion was resolved in the comments to the question, it wasn't reflected in the sole edit made to the question.

Comment: Ah got it! Thanks

Comment: @MoreAnonymous You're welcome! Ping me if/when the question is either edited to resolve this confusion, or, if we resolve this another way that doesn't require an edit (and thus I'll vote to reopen). If you opt for the former, maybe run-by any potential edits with me first, so you aren't editing it multiple times merely to satisfy me.

Comment: an in person meeting would be nice to avoid possible confusions ... Thanks :)

Comment: @MoreAnonymous Yeah, the fact that ongoing dialogue is strongly discouraged on the SE sites (actually prohibited) makes philosophy difficult here since philosophy is rooted in dialogue in my opinion. I find use in Philosophy.SE (I've learned some cool stuff here), but it's utility does seem quite narrow given the SE format.

Comment: I see ... I'll pray